# Md5 hash namespace partition

Tags: java, md5, biginteger

I intend to parition md5 hash (2^128) into four quadrants. I'm using BigInteger java class to represent md5 hash. Below is the code I tried to partition it but seems to be not working:

```
private static final BigInterger chunkSize_ = (new BigInterger(2)).pow(125);
...
byte[] hashValue = new byte[hash.remaining()]; // hash is md5 bytebuffer
hash.get(hashValue);
BigInteger hashNumber = new BigInteger(hashValue);
String chunk = hashNumber.divide(chunkSize_).toString();
```

Collecting stats I see chunk value to as high as 34. Idea was to divide 2^128 into 4 halves. Please let me know what is wrong with above code snippet.

Thanks

Comment: "four halves"

Do you mean 4 fourths?

Comment: What's wrong with just interpreting it as a `String`, and dissecting it into four lots of `8` characters?

Comment: Anubiah, "four halves" means given a hash, the code should be able to classify it into say one of the four quadrants of a circle. Christopher, I want to treat complete hash as one value rather than dissecting it.